# Can Solr JSON Facet API stat functions be combined with a domain filter to limit the results of the function?

Tags: solr

My use case is to make a query to Solr, and to extract counts of unique terms for certain fields within the result set.  The trick is that within my counts, I need to limit the output to only terms that match a certain input string--without adjusting the main Solr query.  E.g., "Solr, give me results for 'War and Peace', and give me the first ten facets on author where the author field has 'doge' in it, and give me a count of *all* unique author values in the result set where the author field has 'doge' in it."

The Solr [JSON Facet API](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/json-facet-api.html) allows me to facet using [stat functions](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/json-facet-api.html#stat-facet-functions); in this case, I'm interested in using the unique() function to get the counts I need.  So, e.g.,

```
{
    "author_count": "unique(author)"
}
```

...tells me the total number of unique values for 'author' in the result set.  This is good.

I can limit the output of a facet using the [domain change](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/json-faceting-domain-changes.html) option, like so:

```
{
    "author_facet": {
        "type": "terms",
        "field": "author",
        "mincount": 1,
        "limit": 10,
        "offset": 0,
        "domain": {
            "filter": "author:doge"
        }
    }
}
```

This is also good.

The problem I'm having is that when I send both of these choices, the result of the unique() call (in author_count) is a count of all unique author values in the base result set, *regardless of whether the author contains 'doge'*.  The author_facet results do correctly limit the output to only authors with 'doge' in them.  But I need to also apply that limit to the results of the unique() function.

I cannot alter the base query, because it represents user input that is independent of the facet filtering input.  E.g, the user will have searched for "War and Peace," and now want to see only those facets where the author is 'doge', with a count of the total authors matching 'doge'.

If it is meaningful to the answer, I am running Solr 9.0.0.

Is there a way to apply domain filtering to Solr stat functions in the JSON Facet API, such as unique()?

EDIT: To clarify: The number of authors with 'doge' may be very large, and so would exceed the number of actual facets that should be returned.  I'm limiting the facet response to 100, but there could be 978 authors with 'doge'.  I want to inform the user of that 978 count while only returning the top 100.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do at the moment is to add it as a subfilter to a "matchAll" query facet. In your example:

```
author_count": {
            "type": "query",
            "query": "*:*",
            "domain": { "filter": "author:doge" } 
            "limit": 1,
            "facet": {
                "count": {
                    "func": "unique(author)",
                    "type": "func"
                }
}
```

Apparently, domain changes are currently (at least version 9.2.1) not supported in Solr: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11709